# Extract string between start string and end string using javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
<div align="Left">
<font style='font-size:17pt; font-family:Times New Roman;color:#000000;'>
<textformat tabstops="[20]" leftmargin="0">Hi all</textformat>
</font>
</div>
```

I want to extract string between "font-size" and "pt" i.e  it should out me a decimal "17" using  javascript.
Can this can be achieved using regular expression.

Thanks in advance,
Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
var pt = string.match(/font-size:([\d.])+pt/)[1];
```

What do you want to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

In the case you just want to get the font size of the respective element I would recommend not relying on parsing the string but rather access this property by using the DOM – as for example something like:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('font')[0].style.fontSize
```